# Blender 3.0: Transfer UV map from shader to geometry nodes?

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

So, I have my object UV unwrapped and textured with, say, an image texture.
How can I transfer this UV map to the geometry nodes setup, so I can use my image texture to affect, say, image scale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Currently there is no specific node to access UVMap coordinates inside Geometry Nodes, but you can use a Vector type input and set it as an Attribute instead of a single value, and then select the UVMap data from the face corners domain in the modifiers panel.

[image]

Answer based on [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwCCCR_BLdQ).

Comment: very nice video link....!

Comment: @Chris highly recommend the channel !

Comment: I knew that person from Twitter before. Makes great things 