# Geonodes, use image texture

Tags: texturing, uv, image, geometry-nodes

If I use generated noise texture to select some vertex, it's oK
[image]
But if image texture are used, all vertices will be select. Why?

Can I use the image texture to select vertices?

[image]

Comment: Is your mesh UV unwrapped ?

Comment: You probably lost (or never had) UV coordinates. If you need reuse existing UV check [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249174/blender-3-0-transfer-uv-map-from-shader-to-geometry-nodes). If you don't have any you would have to position the texture like [here](https://imgur.com/VUsTgRX) ... by default a texture is placed with left-down corner at objects origin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to Get UVMap Attribute from object info node? (Geometry Nodes)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259314/is-it-possible-to-get-uvmap-attribute-from-object-info-node-geometry-nodes)

Comment: @vklidu, grid, that I use is generated by geonodes. It can't have uv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*For you Mesh Primitive > Grid, Hulifier's answer seems to be the best.*

---

### UV Unwrap node

Since 3.3.0 Alpha, Geometry Nodes include an unwrap node that generates a new UV map, mainly used for newly created complex geometry by GN.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

do you mean like this?

[image]

[image]

Note: depending on your image (size) you may want to change the scale and add node values so that you can see "something".

Also it might be necessary to stretch the position values a bit so that the image won't get distorted (you can do this with a vector math multiply node)

..and of course you could use "more intelligent" ways to determine whether the instance should be shown or not than just compare alpha with greater than. You could e.g. take just the red value of the color value of the image texture...or whatever

unfortunately there is no "automated" way up to now to get the size of an image to adapt the size of the grid proportionally.

Answer (score 6):

The grid generated by *Geometry Nodes* comes with an UV attribute:

[image]

Knowing that, you can use it as input to the *Image Texture* node.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 nice spot :)